# Duplicate 'System.Reflection.Assembly.*' attribute and type not found in ASP.NET Core MVC (xUnit Test)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application. Build succeeds without any errors in the project.

In the same solution, I created a xUnit test project as you can see the folder structure below:

[image: FolderStructure]

The unit test file code is:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NetCoreMvcWebApp.Controllers;

namespace TestMvcApp
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            HomeController h = new HomeController(null);
            var res = (ViewResult)h.Index();
            var outdata = res.ViewData["SomeData"];
            Assert.IsType<DateTime>(outdata);
        }
    }
}
```

Added the ASP.NET Core MVC web application as a project reference to the test project dependencies.

When I build the solution or test project, I get these errors without any squiggly lines in the code files:

> Error CS0246
> The type or namespace name 'Fact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    NetCoreMvcWebApp
>
> Error CS0246
> The type or namespace name 'FactAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   NetCoreMvcWebApp
>
> Error CS0579
> Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute  NetCoreMvcWebApp

[image: ErrorList]

How to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating the solution (Suppose .NET Core Web App) in the Visual Studio, it will ask you to check/uncheck the box of "Place Solution and project in same directory".

- do not check it so that your solution and project will come in a different folder structure and whatever the project you'll add to that solution file can be added as individual projects.
- You can add the other projects as a reference to the new projects added to the solution file.

Now, Create the ASP.NET Core 6 MVc App from the Scratch in Visual studo and remember to uncheck the option of "Placing sln and proj in the same directory"

[image]

Then add the xUnit Test project to the same solution file where you'll not get any type of errors.